# Could south poles of magnets repel hydrogen plasma?

Tags: magnetic-fields, fusion

In a fusion reactor there is magnetic confinement so their must be some interaction. So if you put a bar magnet (for simplicity's sake) in hydrogen plasma what would happen.

I am only in high school but very interested in physics so a low level answer would be best. I have looked into the charge of hydrogen ions which I know are positive so assume their could be interaction but cannot find anything understandable explaining the above question.

Thanks

I have found this may relate to magnetic moments but I'm unsure what effect this may have, whether it would allign it or attract.

Comment: I am flagging this for low quality - the content is 2 lines long and doesn't seem to show any research or effort on the part of OP

Comment: I have edited the question, @Cursed1701

Comment: Usually, in a magnetic confined chamber, the magnetic field is far bigger than any bar magnet known on Earth could produce. So whatever the nature of the plasma, your magnet will do nothing of interest. It will deform the lines of force of the magnetic field, yet in a perturbative manner. To confine using magnetic field, you need lines of force able to stuck/trap matter, a bar magnet does not produce such kind of magnetic field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A plasma is nothing else than an ionized gas consisting of ions and electrons (and neutrals). The ions and electrons have an electric charge and are thus influenced in their motion by electric and magnetic fields according to the [Lorentz force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force), a physical effect which you will learn/discuss in high school.

Magnetic fields are indeed commonly used to confine plasmas. With appropriate magnetic fields you try to prevent the plasma to flow to the wall where the ionized particles would recombine and thus be lost. You can use coils on a larger scale or, as you suggested, permanent magnets on a smaller scale. In small experiments with permanent magnets, for example, the plasma density can be increased by up to two orders of magnitude (a factor of 100).